# RequireJS: finding the script responsible for an error

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm looking for an elegant way to find out the full path to a script that caused a timeout error (i.e. failed to load a dependency).

```
requirejs.onError = function (err) {

   // this works:
   var script_that_failed_loading = err.originalError.target.src

   // now I want:
   var the_script_responsible_for_this = <???>

};
```

Comment: That's cool, but I only get the requireJS stack trace, and there's no hint whatsoever in the error event about the script that actually failed.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've been wracking my brain for an hour on this. Grr.

Comment: No, unfortunately I gave up.

Answer (score 8):

Use [loader level errorbacks](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks)

```
require(["foo","bar"],function(foo,bar){
  // perform some action
},function(error){
  // handle error here
});
```

Note that failed module name is given in `error.requireModules`. Such errorbacks can be used both for loaders and modules. If you have multiple fallback paths for a resource, use [path fallbacks](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks).

As per my personal experience, I humbly disagree with **ddotsenko**. We're using RequireJS in our production environment. If setup properly, RJS is very reliable.

Comment: So you suggest adding one error handler by file basically ? Is that something you actually do / recommend ?

Comment: I don't believe ddotsenko is actually "against" Require itself but rather some of it's internal mechanisms. I can see his point which doesn't stop me from using it on a daily basis. FYI, you can actually use Curl.JS (8K) alongside Require based code to load your minified script on production.

Comment: I believe AMD errors should be handled on per file basis if you want to provide fallback mechanisms. If you're concerned only about error notification, it can be done at the global level. Although we rarely face issues with about 40 modules, don't know how much you're working with. Thanks for more info about Curl.

Comment: why not using the [global onError function](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#requirejsonerror)? it exposes the same error properties as a local callback...

Comment: It's more about where you want to write the "fallback" logic, using global onError method is not wrong in any way. For me it makes more sense to write the fallback logic for a given module *along* with the module, in contrast to writing the fallback logic for all modules at a single place. Obviously this is more of a design decision.

Answer (score 2):

RequireJS chose a somewhat unreliable, disconnected mechanism for catching errors. It uses a timer to see if what it expected to get it got. Some other AMD loaders use other, more direct mechanisms to detect error conditions during loading.

My preferred AMD loader is [CurlJS](https://github.com/cujojs/curl), which is hard-wired to catch the loading / parsing errors.

Because of the architectural choice it is more reliably detecting error conditions and you can attach error handlers directly to each `require` call. If stuff like error catching is important to you, I strongly suggest looking at CurlJS.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's not possible? I don't think he wants error handling as much as a diagnostic of which script broke the object graph load.